# OPENMPI install error

Tags: linux, installation, openmpi

```
 runtime/ompi_mpi_init.c:218:46: error: ‘mpi_fortran_status_ignore_’ undeclared here (not in a function)
MPI_Fint *MPI_F_STATUS_IGNORE = (MPI_Fint*) &mpi_fortran_status_ignore_;
                                              ^
runtime/ompi_mpi_init.c:219:48: error: ‘mpi_fortran_statuses_ignore_’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 MPI_Fint *MPI_F_STATUSES_IGNORE = (MPI_Fint*) &mpi_fortran_statuses_ignore_;
                                                ^
runtime/ompi_mpi_init.c: In function ‘ompi_mpi_init’:
runtime/ompi_mpi_init.c:485:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘asprintf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
         asprintf(&cmd, "OMPI_COMMAND=%s", argv[0]);
         ^
runtime/ompi_mpi_init.c:491:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘asprintf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
         asprintf(&av, "OMPI_ARGV=%s", tmp);
         ^
Makefile:3177: recipe for target 'runtime/ompi_mpi_init.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [runtime/ompi_mpi_init.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nitesh/Documents/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi'
Makefile:3324: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nitesh/Documents/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi'
Makefile:1800: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I am having the above error while installing open mpi.I am using gcc and gfortran as compilers. Can anyone help?